# Duplicating logs from multiple targets into single one

Tags: c#, nlog

I have multiple file targets:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
    fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=dd-MM HH\:mm\:ss}[${var:passNumber" + i.ToString() + "}][${var:TestName" + i.ToString() + "}] - ${message}";

    fileTarget.FileName = string.Format(@"log-cell{0}.txt", i);
    fileTarget.KeepFileOpen = false;
    config.AddTarget(string.Format("file{0}", i), fileTarget);

    var ruleFile = new LoggingRule(string.Format("{0}", i), LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleFile);
}
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Then I can access individual rule and write to corresponding target:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["passNumber1"] = 33.ToString();
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["TestName1"] = "Test1";
LogManager.GetLogger("1").Debug("Test1");

LogManager.Configuration.Variables["passNumber2"] = 44.ToString();
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["TestName2"] = "Another Test";
LogManager.GetLogger("2").Debug("Test2");
```

This works fine and creating different file for each rule. Now what I want additionally is to have single `RichTextBoxTarget` or in general let's say special target:

- Where all possible logs will be duplicated or only up to selective level
- Layout will include same formatting/variables like in file target

I am not sure how to have single target with multiple layout. My attempt was to add the following into the loop

```
var ruleWnd = new LoggingRule(string.Format("{0}", i), LogLevel.Debug, rtTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleWnd);
```

Which of course loggine the message, but I am losing the variables. 
So the question is how to add single target, which will capture all logs(or level controller), including defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is how to add single target, which will capture all logs(or level controller), including defined variables.

The variables are on global level, so you could use only one.

In this case "event properties" is where you're looking for. Usage:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Test1");
theEvent.Properties["passNumber"] = 33;
logger.Debug(theEvent);
```

use in your config:

```
${event-properties:item=passNumber}
```

See [${event-properties} docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Event-context%20layout%20renderer)